# Custom claims IdentityServer4 and Angular5 with Oidc-Client

Tags: identityserver4, claims

I am using identityserver4 with aspnetIdentity for usermanagerment

From AccountController(sample code) - Login method is called and returns the tokens but token does not contain any claim, I implementted IprofileService also but the Endpoint is never hit.
In Database -
I added IdentityResource,Identityclaims forthat IdentityResource and mark the Client with alwaysincludeClaimsinToken

In IdentityServer IProfile service is added as given in the some examples
But all this is not calling the Profileservice and no information is added in token apart from standard id_token information
Do let me know what Am I missing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the Iprofileservie implementation does not work with localhost configuration while the same is working when deployed on actual server.
I added properties to ASNEtUSers.
Added IdentityResource and IdentityResourceClaim data
and In Profileservice added the claims if it is asked by client dynamically.